# Userform .setfocus and _Change events

Tags: vba, userform, setfocus

I created a Userform consisting of a textbox and drop-down menu. The idea is for users to complete the textbox, and hit "save", which pastes the value entered onto a corresponding cell in the excel workbook.

Since the information entered in the drop-down menu can change over time, I formatted the textbox to display when last the field was changed by a user.

To do this, I created a _CHANGE event on the drop-down menu, and specified that if the selection changes, the textbox must apply  = NOW, which consequently shows the date and time. This works fine in itself.

The problem arises when the USERFORM is initialized. Its code contains a .SETFOCUS for the drop-down menu to display its existing value. It appears as if the .SETFOCUS on the USERFORM_INITIALISE act as _CHANGE event on the drop-down menu, which causes it to edit the date and time before a user actually changes the field.

How can I go about to change this?

```
Private Sub drop_down_menu_change()
        textbox.Value = Now
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

drop_down_menu.AddItem "1"
drop_down_menu.AddItem "2"
drop_down_menu.AddItem "3"
drop_down_menu.AddItem "4"
drop_down_menu.AddItem "5"

drop_down_menu.SetFocus

  End Sub
```

Below is a screenshot of the userform as well as the code:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "drop-down menu"? Isn't it a combo box?

Comment: That's what I meant, sorry.

Comment: And didn't my answer code solve your problem? Did you test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the `Initialize` event, it is normal to trigger the `Change` event when the code adds items...

You can overpass the problem creating a `Boolean` variable, able to make the event to work only after form initialization. Something like this:

1. Declare a variable in the top form code module area (declarations area):

```
Private noEvent As Boolean
```

2. In the initialization event use it in this way:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   noEvent = True

   drop_down_menu.AddItem "1"
   drop_down_menu.AddItem "2"
   drop_down_menu.AddItem "3"
   drop_down_menu.AddItem "4"
   drop_down_menu.AddItem "5"

   drop_down_menu.SetFocus
    
    noEvent = False
End Sub
```

3. And the event should be transformed in:

```
Private Sub drop_down_menu_change()
   if not noEvent Then textbox.Value = Now
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, `EventsEnabled = False` does not work as it should, for the form controls...